# react - can you mutate modify this.props.children to dynamically (programatically) add children components

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

According to fb docs, `this.props.children` is an opaque data structure and should not be manipulated directly.

In fact, the docs say that we should use the library functions in [`React.Children`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children)

Looking at the library functions, they are all getters, which leads me to believe that we should not be mutating `this.props.children`

Is this true?  Can we mutate `this.props.children` (such as inserting a component dynamically, etc)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't (or shouldn't) mutate the `children` directly. You can however "modify" its output via mapping:

```
const Hydrogen = props => (<div>{props.weight}</div>);
const Oxygen = props => (<div>{props.weight}</div>);

const Water = props => (
    <div className='water'>
    {React.Children.map(props.children, child => (
        React.cloneElement(child, {
            weight: props.weight / React.Children.count(props.children)
        })
    ))}
    </div>
);

const WaterBalloon = props => (
    <div className='water-balloon'>
        <Water weight={3}>
            <Hydrogen />
            <Hydrogen />
            <Oxygen />
        </Water>
    </div>
);
```

Here I "modify" the children passed to Water, passing the weight property to them.

If you need the ability to "add/remove", perhaps you should consider redesigning in such a way that you maintain an array of "data" and then populate components from that data:

https://jsfiddle.net/814jze3z/

```
const Item = props => (
    <li>{props.time}</li>
);

class List extends React.Component
{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            items: []
        };

        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
        this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
    }

    addItem() {
        let item = {
            id: this.state.items.length + 1,
            time: +new Date()
        };

        this.setState({
            items: this.state.items.concat([item])
        });
    }

    removeItem() {
        this.setState({
            items: this.state.items.concat().splice(1)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add Item</button>
                <button onClick={this.removeItem}>Remove Item</button>
                <ul className='list'>
                {this.state.items.map(item => (
                    <Item key={item.id} time={item.time} />
                ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful. However, this doesn't bode well for being able to create a component that can dynamically have components added to its insides; cloning the component itself, just to add new components, per your answer, seems like one way, but it doesn't seem to be an optimal (ie, efficient) way of doing things. However, it should be passable if its just for UI (as is the intention), where users won't be adding or removing components more than once per second.

Comment: Yes, thanks for updating. I actually did end up having to use the array of data, which seems a kludge way, rather than using fb's this.prop.children.

Comment: The reason using your own array is kludge, is that, with using an array, you now lose the semantic ability to non-programatically specify your iner components (ie, in the jsx markup).  With this.props.children, you have the semantic ability, but lose the programmatic ability unless you resort to rampant cloning. Either way, I see this as a shortcoming of React, currently, and they need to address the non-mutability of this.props.children, perhaps by providing mutators in React.Children